# Child who was cast out but ended up succeeding?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

I'm looking for a word for a child who was cast out, cast aside, ignored or discriminated against relative to other children, but ended up succeeding despite it all.

Used in a sentence:

> Alice winced at the mention of Bob's name. Hearing strangers extolling her _________ brought more pain than even the thought of him lying half-dead in some ditch, before he had returned.

Notes:

- Could be either a noun, or an adjective you can place before "son" or "daughter".
- Didn't really have a good search term for thesauri (I tried thesaurus.com with "successful bastard" and "successful orphan")
- Doesn't matter if it's a gendered expression or not.
- I don't have obvious criteria for choosing the best word.

Comment: There is probably some name from literature that would work, though none is coming to mind.

Comment: Oliver Twist, for example.

Comment: Are you sure this is really what you are looking for?  I think your question is literary rather than linguistic.  At the least, a broader context is needed.  From the quotation you give, it sounds as if the potential of the character has already been either recognised or even fulfilled.

Comment: @Tuffy: My question does not require the child's potential to not have been recognized in the past and recognized now. Also, there's the question of _who_ recognizes that potential. The sentence is just an example; my question is what it is...

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica Then I doubt there is a single word or even short phrase for what you are seeking.  But that is why you need to explain the background more fully/clearly.  If you do, the right expression will probably occur to you before it does to anyone else.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly "[Prodigal son](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prodigal-son)" or daughter, from the [biblical story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable_of_the_Prodigal_Son).

[Resilience](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/resilience) or [resilient](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/resilient)' would be a word to describe the character of the ignored child.

*Alice winced at the mention of Bob's name. Hearing strangers extolling her **resilience** brought more pain than even the thought of him lying half-dead in some ditch...*

Comment: Not really, neither of the sons fits. Specifically, the prodigal son leaves of his own accord, not cast out; and has failed, or is penitent, or has remorse. Also, the prodigal son _returns_. I didn't say the child has to have returned - that was just in my example sentence.

Comment: You may want to remove the 'return' statement from your question, if it is not significant to the meaning.

Comment: I did not mention "return" in the question itself, just in the example.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking up 'dead in some ditch' from Jane Eyre, which brought me here. It is probably too late for you now, but 'Jane-Eyre-like' or similar might suit the need. Jane Eyre is discriminated against by her Aunt who brings her up (particularly in comparison to her cousins). She is cast out to a paupers' school aged 10, and leaves aged 20 to better herself. She ends up as a successful governess and then making a good marriage and living happily ever after.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).